# Code Igniter file cache – more misses than expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

We're currently using Code Igniter's file cache to optimize a heavy DB query which is called often in our multi-user environment, but doesn't change often. The cache is set to expire every 60 seconds, so that would suggest the query would be called about 60 times an hour. In the DB monitor, we're seeing the query invoked 340 ± 150 times per hour, or almost six times as frequently as expected.

The code is nothing special, all in one function:

```
// Cache identifier
$cache = 'cache-identifier';

// Try to pull from the cache first
if ($working = $this->cache->file->get($cache))
    return $working;

// Cache didn't work out, query directly
$sql = '<<heavy-DB-query>>';
$working = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

// Save the cache (note essentially redundant check: $working is 99.95% non-null)
if ($working)
    $this->cache->file->save($cache, $working, 60);

return $working;
```

We do see a significant reduction compared to non-caching but would like to optimize more. Any ideas why would it be missing so often?

Some more details:

Prior to caching, we were getting the DB query invoked about 3,000 calls/hour (≈ 50 calls/minute). So 340 calls/hour (≈ 5½ calls/minute) is a significant improvement. We tried outputting to a log file whenever there's a miss, but the act of doing that seems to change the dynamics and the statistics aren't the same.

Testing in isolation, single user, from browser to server and back, a miss takes about 1.0 s, and a hit about 0.6 s. The query itself is about 0.1 s, but with overhead, server to DB and back is about 0.5 s.

I think what might be going on is that side effects from other activities are causing the users to synchronize, so that we get the queries bunched up and not random. The first one has a miss, makes the query, same with second, third and so on, until the first gets the results back. Then the remainder for that minute get hits. Given the times involved, seeing 5½ calls a minute would fit this hypothesis more-or-less. But how to test?

Even more:

Turns out the server access logs had the answer. They were indeed showing groups of multiple queries with the same time stamp. Turns out the users often have multiple windows open in the same browser, and in this scenario, the queries do tend to synchronize. I've added a random element to the timer to break up this synchronization. So far, seems to be better. Now that I know what's going on, I'll be happy with ≈2 calls/minute!

Comment: I would rather recommend an in-memory-cache like redis/apcu/memcached or similar. It's good not to rely on files (poor performance in comparison to in-memory).

Comment: but that doesn't address the hit-rate. Regardless of what caching mechanism is used, the hit-rate would be the same